# Custom jquery validation always return true

Tags: jquery

I have created a custom jquery validation and my validation always fails(returns true always), i spent hours but could not figure out what went wrong in my code:

```
var isvalid = [];
var counterrors = isvalid.length;
function salutationvalidation(){

    var salutation = $("#salutation option").attr("selected");
    var salutation_error = $("#salutation").parent(".form-input").siblings(".form-info").children(".1stperror");

    if(salutation!=undefined){
        $(salutation_error).css("display","table-cell");
        isvalid.push(salutation_error);
    }else{
        $(salutation_error).css("display","none");
        isvalid.pop(salutation_error);
    }

}

function namevalidation(){
    var checkname = $("#first-name").val();
    var namevalid = new RegExp("(^[a-zA-Z'-]+$)");
    var name_error = $("#first-name").parent(".form-input").siblings(".form-info").children(".1stperror");

    if(checkname.match(namevalid)){
        $(name_error).css("display","table-cell");
        isvalid.push(name_error);
    }else{
        $(name_error).css("display","none");
        isvalid.pop(name_error);
    }

}

$("#form-v2").submit(function(){
    salutationvalidation();
    namevalidation();
    if(counterrors == 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Any help to solve the above code would much be appreciated, as i have to cater for 4 other input fields as well. When i alert counterrors i get 4, sometimes 5,6. Seems the values are not clearing

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
$("#form-v2").submit(function(){
    salutationvalidation();
    namevalidation();
    counterrors = isvalid.length;
    if(counterrors == 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: My code was initially like this.. it did not work. Ithink there could be an issue with my (push, Pop)